# Catch f5 in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I have an app that uses the navigation controls. What I would like is for my app to stay on the page it is showing rather than reload the whole application when f5 (refresh) is pressed?

Is this at all possible?

JD.

Comment: Actually when you are inside a SL app and press F5 nothing happens.

Comment: It seems to reload the app in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the way to do it is with the contentFrame_navegating event. On refresh, the URL that the user is on is passed through. We can then use to to redirect as the application will try to load the default page.

JD.